# Post com x-www-form-urlencoded no Angular

Tags: angular, http, typescript

Olá, tenho um requisição POST que é de content-type: x-www-form-urlencoded.

Preciso passar alguns parâmetros no meu Body, desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou fazendo dessa maneira abaixo para add meus parametros no body da requisição:

```js
  ObtendoToken(): Observable<string> {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

    const body = new URLSearchParams();
    body.set('grant_type', 'password');
    body.set('username', 'varejo_user');
    body.set('password', 'w6h5xgtl');

    return this.http.post(`${ApiDeSegurança}`, body, new RequestOptions({headers: headers})).map(response => response.json());
  }
```

Porém está retornando este erro:

***error":"unsupported_grant_type***

Acredito que seja na criação dos parâmetros do body. Não estou conseguindo resolver, pois é minha primeira requisição POST no angular!

Agradeço desde já....

---

Reiniciei minha aplicação angular e tentei usar o mesmo método e o erro voltou a ocorrer...

***Novo método com o mesmo erro de: unsupported_grant_type***

```js
 ObtendoToken(): Observable<string> {
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  const body = {grant_type: 'password', username: 'varejo_user', password: 'w6h5xgtl'}; 

  return this.http.post(`${ApiDeSegurança}`, body, new RequestOptions({headers: headers})).map(response => response.json());
}
```

Comment: tenta  apensas criar um objeto com o body...

body = { grant_type : 'password' , username: 'varejo_user' , password: 'w6h5xgtl' } ;

Comment: Funcionou 100%! se quiser criar uma resposta eu aprovo daqui! muito obrigado...

Comment: Show ! vou colocar ali. Foi nada :)

Comment: Lucas eu reiniciei, minha aplicação angular e tentei realizar o mesmo código e voltou a dar o mesmo erro....Vou adicionar o novo método na pergunta...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que o Body, tem que está no tipo de string e não como um objeto.

Desta maneira:

```js
let grant_type = 'password';
let username = 'varejo_user';
let password = 'w6h5xgtl';
let body = `grant_type=${grant_type}&username=${username}&password=${password}`;
```

Assim, funcionou normalmente. Não entendo como da primeira vez funcionou rs.

O método inteiro fica desse jeito:

```js
ObtendoNovoToken(): Observable<string> {
  const header = new Headers();
  header.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  let grant_type = 'password';
  let username = 'varejo_user';
  let password = 'w6h5xgtl';
  let body = `grant_type=${grant_type}&username=${username}&password=${password}`;

  return this.http.post(`${ApiDeSegurança}`, body, new RequestOptions({headers: header})).map(response=> response.json())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

tenta passar o body apenas como um objeto:

```
body = {
 grant_type : 'password' , 
 username: 'varejo_user' , 
 password: 'w6h5xgtl' 
} ;
```

Ficando da seguinte maneira:

```js
ObtendoToken(): Observable<string> {
const body = {grant_type: 'password', username: 'varejo_user', password: 'w6h5xgtl'}
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

return this.http.post(`${ApiDeSegurança}`, body, new RequestOptions({headers: headers})).map(response => response.json());
}
```

Comment: Lucas eu reiniciei, minha aplicação angular e tentei realizar o mesmo código e voltou a dar o mesmo erro....Vou adicionar o novo método na pergunta...

Comment: Que estranho. Nunca passei por isso.